# How to find keys in hash by number of values? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to search through a hash for keys with only one value, and divide that value by 2.  How do I go about this?

Example

```
hash = { a => [4], b => [2, 4, 5], c => [3, 5] }
```

Result sought

```
hash = { a => [2], b => [2, 4, 5], c => [3, 5] }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example hash and output?

Comment: Tristin, in order to get some help, help yourself by putting more effort into the question by being more specific. As mentioned an example may help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I had assumed it wouldn't be necessary but will not make this mistake again. :-)

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Comment: "How do I go about this?" – By writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 2):

```
hash = {:a=>[4], :b=>[2, 4, 5], :c=>[3, 5]}
```

You can use `transform_values`:

```
hash.transform_values { |v| v.one? ? [v[0]/2.0] : v }
#=> {:a=>[2.0], :b=>[2, 4, 5], :c=>[3, 5]}
```

Or `map`

```
hash.map { |k,v| v.one? ? [k,[v[0]/2.0]] : [k,v] }.to_h                          
#=> {:a=>[2.0], :b=>[2, 4, 5], :c=>[3, 5]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, just iterate over each key/value pair and check the length of the values, if it only has 1 item, set the key in the hash to be equal to half the original value.

```
hash = { a: [4], b:  [2, 4, 5], c: [3, 5] }
# => {:a=>[4], :b=>[2, 4, 5], :c=>[3, 5]}

hash.each do |key, values|
  if 1 == values.length
    hash[key] = [values.first / 2]
  end
end
# => {:a=>[2], :b=>[2, 4, 5], :c=>[3, 5]}
```

Comment: Nice answer, slightly spoiled by the inclusion of your irb-prompts :(

Comment: @sagarpandya82 you're right, not sure why I didn't clean that up some when I posted this...fixed now though